# Slice a 3d pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a nested 3-dimensional pandas DataFrame, like so:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([k for k in range(10)]) for j in range(5)] for i in range(8))
```

I want to slice this dataframe so that the the length of the series of the k-dimension is half of their current length (10).

I've tried `data.iloc[:,:][0:6]` but this simply returns the first 6 rows (i-dimension). I've also tried iterating through the whole dataframe and replacing each cell but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way of doing this.

Comment: There is no such thing as 3D DataFrame, you have here a DataFrame of objects (lists), which unfortunately you cannot use in a vectorial manner. You should use a numpy ndarray here (or loop the DataFrame, which is inefficient…).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**:

Here is a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([k for k in range(10)]) for j in range(5)] for i in range(8))
ni, nj = data.shape
nk = len(data.loc[0, 0])
print(ni, nj, nk)

data2 = data.applymap(lambda x: x[:len(x) // 2])
print(*data2.shape, len(data2.loc[0, 0]))
```

Output:

```
8 5 10
8 5 5
```

---

If your data were in a 3D numpy array, it would be possible to actually slice the 3D array.

Here is a round-trip pandas-to-numpy-to-pandas solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([k for k in range(10)]) for j in range(5)] for i in range(8))
ni, nj = data.shape
nk = len(data.loc[0, 0])
print(ni, nj, nk)

xf = [y.to_numpy() for y in data.to_numpy().flatten()]
n = np.array(xf).reshape([ni, nj, nk])
print(n.shape)
print(n)

n2 = n[:, :, :nk // 2]
print(n2.shape)
print(n2)

data2 = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(n2[i, j, :]) for j in range(n2.shape[1])] for i in range(n2.shape[0]))
ni, nj = data2.shape
nk = len(data2.loc[0, 0])
print(ni, nj, nk)
```

Here is the input converted from an i x j dataframe containing k-length Series values to a 3D numpy array `n`:

```
[[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]]
```

Here is the 3D numpy array `n2` which has a k-extent of half that of the original 3D array (nk // 2):

```
[[[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 3 4]]]
```

As a final step, the sliced 3D numpy array `n2` is converted back to an i x j dataframe containing Series values of length nk // 2.

Comment: @perceptronEnthusiast420 Do you need more help with this?